# Track entry into blank row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that lists our company's customers (A21:A250 is formatted but only A21:A106 currently have data). What I would like to do is count new customers when an entry is made into the next blank row. I've tried a few different methods but to no avail. Here's what I've been working on.

I have tried formulas in the sheet itself (COUNTIF not blank). That works like it should but the issue is that I need to capture the new customers by month (columns after A for months). I've created another spreadsheet that has a button I click on once per month to import data thereby capturing what those numbers were on that day.

```
function newCustomers() {
  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('BACKLOG');
  var lrow = sourceSheet.getLastRow();
  var range = sourceSheet.getRange(21, 1, lrow, 1);
  var data = range.getValues();
  var countNew = 0;

  for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][0] !== null) {
    countNew++
   }
 }
   Logger.log('New Customers' + countNew)
}
```

The above code works but reports back 250 (the last blank column in the range) in the log each time it runs. How can I change this to only count cells in column A that have no data entered into them?

Comment: `""` is not strictly equal to `null`. Empty cells are read as `""` (as are cells with formulas that currently return `""`). So because none of the acquired cell values is exactly `null`, you get 250 as the reported end.

Comment: Of course, thank you! I knew I was just missing something simple. I felt like it was on the tip of my brain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function newCustomers() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var srcsh=ss.getSheetByName('BACKLOG');
  var startrow=21;
  var rg=srcsh.getRange(startrow, 1, srcsh.getLastRow()-startrow + 1, 1);
  var dA=rg.getValues();
  var count=0;
  for (var i=0;i<dA.length;i++) {
    if(dA[i][0] && dA[i][0].length>0) {
      count++;
    }
  } 
  var html=Utilities.formatString('Count: %s', count);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html),'Count');
}
```

Comment: The code I had above works but I do like yours better. I did just think of one thing though, the way I have it set up it doesn't really compare the current number with the previous one so if I were to add a new customer in January it would be counted again when I ran the script in February. In the script I'm using now I am subtracting 86 (number of customers on Jan 1st) from the variable newCustomers (which would only work in January). What would be the best way to handle this? Can I set another variable equal to newCustomer to be used to compare the next month?

Comment: Do you have another column that has the date they became a customer?

Comment: I do have a column, F, that has the 1 year anniversary of when they became a customer. I'll see what I can do with that!

Comment: Get the month from that date to make your reports `new Date(dA[i][?]).getMonth()`